# If deg$(v) \geq k$ for all $v \in V(G)$, then G contains a matching of cardinality $\min \{k,\lfloor{\frac{|V|}{2}}\rfloor\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let$G = (V; E)$ be an undirected graph. Show that if deg$(v) \geq k$
>   for all $v \in V$, then G contains a matching of cardinality $\min \{k,\lfloor{\frac{|V|}{2}}\rfloor\}$.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For any vertex $v$ of $G$, you can only pick one of its $\geq k$ adjacent edges in a matching, and each edge in the matching is picked simultaneously for two vertices. If there is no matching of size at least $k$, what does this say about the number of vertices?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand our argument. Can you give me more clearly explanation?

Comment: @ThomasEdison Well, the best you can ever hope for in terms of the size of a maximum matching is $\left\lfloor |V|/2 \right\rfloor$, since you can hope to pick one edge per pair of vertices. From here you can argue that if there is no matching of size at least $k$, there must be fewer than $2k$ vertices in the graph, in which case the other bound must win.

Comment: Hi Yusim, I don't think that this statement is correct "if there is no matching of size at least k, there must be fewer than 2k vertices in the graph". For example, I have maximum matching of size $k-1$ and many vertices connected to a vertex in a matching.

Comment: @ThomasEdison If you have a maximum matching of size $k-1$ and every vertex has degree at least $k$, then for every vertex in the matching, there is at least one adjacent vertex $v$ which is unmatched. If $v$ is the only such vertex, then there are $2(k-1)+1 < 2k$ vertices. Otherwise there are at least 2k vertices.

Comment: @ThomasEdison I can perform the following algorithm to get a matching of size $k$ if there are at least $2k$ vertices: pick a vertex $v$. Of its unmatched neighbours, pick one, say $u$, and add the edge $uv$ to the matching. Pick a different neighbour $n$ of $v$ and repeat, starting on $n$. At step $i \leq k$, at most $i-1$ neighbours of $n$ will have been previously matched, so the algorithm can continue to at least step $k$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I got an idea to prove this by contradiction and augmenting path.