# Simple graph with vertex degree $\geq k$ has a matching of cardinality $\min\{k,\lfloor \frac{|V|}{2}\rfloor\}$

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Essentially, I'm referring to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836988/if-degv-geq-k-for-all-v-in-vg-then-g-contains-a-matching-of-cardinali)

The part I don't understand is why a graph with $|V|<2k$ must have a matching of cardinality $\lfloor \frac{|V|}{2}\rfloor$.

Can someone explain?

The answer given in [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836988/if-degv-geq-k-for-all-v-in-vg-then-g-contains-a-matching-of-cardinali) and comments to the question do not contain the answer to the question neither for the case $k\leq|V|/2$, nor for the case $k>|V|/2$. The reasoning suggested there cannot lead to the proof of the existence of the required matching, because, for example, if graph $G$ is obtained from graph $K_4$ by deleting one edge and we start construction of the matching from an edge connecting two vertices of degree $3$, we cannot complete our process. Note that for graph $G$ we have $k=|V|/2=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, you're right. The post you linked to has too short an answer.
Moreover, I don't see any proof of this statement there even for the case where $k<|V|/2$.

Here is what seems to me to be more plausible reasoning.
Let $k<|V|/2$. If $k=0$, then there is nothing to prove. Let $k\geq1$.

Let's organize such a process. In the first step, choose an arbitrary vertex $x_1$. It has $k$ neighbors. Take its arbitrary neighbor $y_1$. We obtain an edge $x_1y_1$.

Let us already choose edges $x_1y_1,\ldots,x_sy_s$ where $x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_s,y_s$ are pairwise different and $s<k$. Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_s\}$, $Y=\{y_1,\ldots,y_s\}$, and $Z=X\cup Y$.

If there is at least one edge outside $Z$, we can increase our matching.
Let each vertex outside $Z$ be adjacent only to vertices from $Z$. Since $2s<2k<|V|$ there are at least two vertices $x,y\notin Z$.

If there exists $i\in[1,s]$ such that $ux_i,vy_i\in E(G)$, then we add these two edges to our matching and remove edge $x_iy_i$ from it and thus increase our matching.

Let us prove that such $i$ necessarily exists. Let $I_u\subset[1,s]$ and $J_u\subset[1,s]$ be chosen such that $ux_i\in E(G)$ and $uy_j\in E(G)$ for every $i\in I_u$ and every $j\in J_u$.
Since $\operatorname{deg}(u)\geq k$, then $|I_u\cup J_u|\geq k>s$. Similarly determine $I_v$ and $J_v$. If $I_u\cap J_v\neq\emptyset$ or $I_v\cap J_u\neq\emptyset$, then the previous observation works. If $I_u\cap J_v=\emptyset$ and $I_v\cap J_u=\emptyset$, and for example $|I_u|>s/2$, then $|J_v|>s/2$, then $I_u\cap J_v\neq\emptyset$. Contradiction.

The case of $k\geq|V|/2$ is completely similar to the considered one.
After all, in this case we have to build a matching of cardinality $l=|V|/2$.